# What are the bonuses and penalties for checks in heavy seas?

Tags: dnd-5e

I'm building a small ocean based campaign for 5e and I want to throw some heavy weather and possibly an evacuation to a lifeboat.

What bonuses and penalties apply to combat and skill checks on a vessel that is rolling and pitching wildly?

Comment: Sure, but I'm thinking at sea it will be erratic. Let's say you run 30ft. You could find yourself running uphill for 15 ft, then frantically downhill for 15ft, as well as dodging untethered items that are on board

Comment: Since you used the [rules-as-written] tag is there something in the DMG or / PHB that you feel is lacking/missing insofar as guidance?

Comment: What modifiers might apply to checks/combat is one question, but how to handle terrain in general is a whole other topic. I've removed that second part so that the answers can focus on one question at a time (and therefore ensure higher quality). If you want to ask about how to handle terrain on a storm-tossed ship, please ask it as a separate question with details about what precise things you don't know how to handle. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'll move it to a more specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to make creative use of advantage and disadvantage, explained on PHB p.7, to arbitrarily represent the circumstantially beneficial or detrimental effects of a given combat situation.

Depending on the circumstances leading up to combat, some characters may have ranks of exhaustion, which are explained on PHB p.291.

Players will likely need to do more object interactions and improvisation during combat, so you'll probably be calling for lots of ability and skill checks. Having the DC benchmarks table and its explanation, PHB p.174 and DMG p.238, may be handy for inventing this stuff on the fly. You'll also likely need to know how much it takes to smash out a window, bash down a door, snap a rope, slash through a sail, etc. Statistics for objects begins on DMG p.246. Related, these activities will likely require you to improvise damage, which is discussed on DMG p.249.

It is probably of some importance to note that boats are vehicles and have a move speed. Though a combat situation may slow all vessels to a stop, it is equally likely that they are moving around- the ships can be fighting each other just as much as characters on those ships can be fighting each other. (Assuming there are still people aboard who are not personally fighting) Being able to represent this may be extremely difficult without some considerable degree of creativity and preparation. If you want to calculate vessel speeds in combat, see DMG p.242, under "Special Travel Pace". Keep in mind, a combat round is 6 seconds. As vessels are involved in combat, it may be necessary to know their AC, HP, and what their damage threshold is, all presented on DMG p.119.

The traps "collapsing roof" and "falling net", DMG p.122, can be repurposed to represent falling rigging and spars. You may also wish to represent the armaments of a vessel in combat using the siege equipment, (such as a cannon) on DMG p.255.

You are going to need to know how to determine both the swim and climb speed of the PCs. If any characters fall off the boat, you need to know how that impacts their movement. The same goes if the characters must climb aloft into the rigging of the sails. In addition to this, knowing how to calculate a character's jump range may become important. All of this can be found on PHB p.182. If any creature falls, you'll want to calculate damage for that. Also, you may need to know suffocation rules, if a character finds themselves trapped under water. Both of these are found on the next page, p.183. Swimming is expanded upon on DMG p.116 under "swimming". That section says that swimming at great depth is similar to flying at high altitudes, so you may want to read "High Altitude" on DMG p.110

You will need to read the section, "Underwater Combat" on PHB p.198. It gives, in no uncertain terms, specific restrictions associated to this sort of situation. This can be expanded upon: DMG p.110 has specific penalties imposed by strong wind and heavy precipitation. It also gives details for how frigid water effects a creature. If your combat is happening in a particularly cold environment, you may include slippery ice (also on the same page) as an environmental hazard. This hazard could be modified or used straight to represent a slippery, roiling deck surface. Visibility Outdoors, DMG p.243, states how rain and fog impact sight range. Which reminds me, the section "Vision and Light", PHB p.183 notes how environmental effects, like fog impact how obscured a character is.

The PHB section "Concentration", where it continues on p.204, specifically gives an example of how spell casting on a stormtossed ship may be effected, although it leaves this mostly up to DM discretion.

The Background Proficiency variant rule, DMG p.264, would make the sailor background extremely useful in combat situations, where characters of other backgrounds may find themselves very limited.

If you want to simulate some more interesting effects from a storm, you may cannibalize a wide variety of spell effects and simply have them happen where and when you wish, rather than having them cast by a creature.

That's everything that I can find in the corebooks that would affect combat at sea.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on how crunchy you want to get as a DM.

The simplest means to address the challenges that heavy seas represent is in the use of *Advantage/Disadvantage*. (PHB p. 57 / DMG p. 239)  For DnD 5e, WoTC put this mechanic into the game to try and reduce the number of bonus calculations (plus / minus / both) and resolve a benefit or penalty as it best fits a given situation.  The idea is to keep play flowing and not bog down play.

#### For spell casters

Beyond advantage/disadvantage, the last paragraph in the *Concentration* entry adds an option to apply to those spells requiring *concentration*. (Basic Rules p. 80)

> The DM might also decide that certain environmental phenomena, such as
>   a wave crashing over you while you’re on a storm-tossed ship, require
>   you to succeed on a DC 10 Constitution saving throw to maintain
>   concentration on a spell.

Applying a concentration check, when needed, and the use of advantage / disadvantage are three tools in the RAW to assist you in adapting the challenge for at sea encounters.

#### Additional optional rules for the melee characters

Wizards of the Coast published an Unearthed Arcana article that included some [Waterborne adventure ideas](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Waterborne_v3.pdf).  One of them is the Mariner fighting style.

Fighting Style: Mariner

> The following new option can be selected by fighters, paladins, and
>   rangers for the Fighting Style class feature.  Whether a buccaneer, an
>   experienced sailor, or a specially trained marine, a mariner can scale
>   a ship’s rigging and swim through choppy water with ease. Adapted to
>   wearing light and medium armor, mariners can defend themselves without
>   relying on heavy armor or bulky shields. Most of them thus wield
>   two‐handed weapons or fight with a pair of blades.

By folding in this fighting style, you could rule that any fighting done by a character lacking this Fighting style is prone to disadvantage when "pitching & rolling deck/rough seas" comes into play.